# Changing Header Row position in grid.table in R

Tags: r, gridextra

I have the following code that I'm using to create a table using `grid.table` from the `gridExtra` package.

```
require(tidyverse)
require(gridExtra)

df<-data.frame(x=letters[1:13],y=1:13)
grid.table(df,rows=NULL)
```

Which generates the following table.

[image: df as an image generated by grid.table]

Is there any way to have the header row of the resulting table in the bottom most row of the table that `grid.table` returns? That's to say a-m being the on top of x and 1-13 being on top of y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can split and recombine the gtable,

```
tg = tableGrob(df,rows=NULL)
grid::grid.draw(rbind(tg[2:nrow(tg),], tg[1,]))
```